# LiDAR Data captured, unsure what units or format this time field is in?

Tags: fields-attributes, gps, lidar, units, datetime

I haven't been able to figure out or find out from searching around what units or format this time field is in my LiDAR data that was collected?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a ballpark idea of when the timestamp should be? Also do you think it's a data, a time, or a datetime?

Comment: It should be around November of 2018. When I load it into QGIS, I get a year of 1970.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LiDAR times often come in GPS time or time since the GPS epoch.  Here is a stack exchange link with more detail ([What is a GPS epoch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281223/what-is-a-gps-epoch)) This look like GPS seconds.  Your data should also include a column of data that shows the GPS week  You can use the week and seconds data to convert the pulse time to human-readable time using a website like [GPS Time Calculator](https://www.labsat.co.uk/index.php/en/gps-time-calculator).  If you have Python still you can use [Module gpstime](http://software.ligo.org/docs/glue/glue.gpstime-module.html).