# LiDAR data in GPS time, only in second. Missing week?

Tags: fields-attributes, gps, lidar, units, datetime

I have LiDAR data [LiDAR Data captured, unsure what units or format this time field is in?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/306270/35779) which I learned that my LiDAR data is in GPS second, however I do not have a column of data which shows the GPS week? Is that something typically collected and should be available in the data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our LiDAR vendors typically provide processed surface models, the LAS/LAZ files, and text files that include the XYZ data plus GPS week and GPS seconds. Maybe the GPS week data was purged from the table shown?